how to create a .npv4 or inpv ssh config file with python
there are some android and iOS application like Npv tunnel or v2ray or napsternetv that you can make a custom configuration for any type of connection like SSH Tunnel or ... and connect to it.
but now i have a ssh host, ssh port, ssh username, ssh password and i need to create a .npv4 file to be imported by my users, I don't want my users to customly type the configuration and save it in the application, but , and i need to create a .npv4 file with python. like a function that receives these ssh parameters and generate a .npv4 file so that i send the file to my users and they import the file to the App easily so that the users don't make mistake in typing the credential.
I dragged a .npv4 file into notepad but it was not a clear text and readable. so i don't know how it's generated. and i have found no document about the file structure. any help would be greatly appreciated
